# how should I specify batch size in LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Is it possible to look at this code in LSTM? I want to train the data with the shape which I put here but I receive an error regarding the size of the batch I think so. I do not know which size of the batch. currently, the size of a batch that I choose is 64. should I put another size for the batch or the error is not related to the size of the batch?

```
should I choose for this code: the shape of X (7311, 17, 124)  and shape of Y(7311, 1) 
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [16] vs. [64]
     [[node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Mul (defined at <ipython-input-74-f95f7e276c58>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_138498]
```

```
df = pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")
timestep = 17 #from 1 to 23 (17 with the current NaN strategy)
threshold_for_classification = -8
X_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
fill_X = -0.01
seed = 11

#RNN hiperparameter
epochs = 75
batch = 64
val_split = 0.25
test_split = 0.25
lr = 0.0001
adam = optimizers.Nadam() #(lr)
class_weight = {True:  5.,
                False: 1.}
verbose = 1
#Dropping first the empty column and then rows with NaNs
df = df.drop("c_rcs_estimate", axis=1)
df = df.dropna(how='any')

#Filtering events with len=1 or min_tca > 2 or max_tca < 2
def conditions(event):
    x = event["time_to_tca"].values
    return ((x.min()<2.0) & (x.max()>2.0) & (x.shape[0]>1))
df = df.groupby('event_id').filter(conditions)

#OHE for c_object_type (5 categories) -> 5 new features
df["mission_id"] = df["mission_id"].astype('category')
df["c_object_type"] = df["c_object_type"].astype('category')
df = pd.get_dummies(df)

#Getting y as 1D-array
y = df.groupby(["event_id"])["risk"].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).values.reshape(-1, 1)

#Scaling y
_ = y_scaler.fit(df["risk"].values.reshape(-1, 1)) #using the whole risk feature to scale the target 'y'
y = y_scaler.transform(y)

#Getting X as df (dropping rows with tca < 2) 
df = df.loc[df["time_to_tca"]>2]

#Adding feature 'event_length' for counting how many instances each event has
df["event_length"] = df.groupby('event_id')['event_id'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())

#Scaling X
df = pd.DataFrame(X_scaler.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns)

#Transforming X into a 3D-array
events = df["event_id"].nunique() #rows
features = len(df.columns) #columns

X = np.zeros((events,timestep,features))
X.fill(fill_X)

i = 0
def df_to_3darray(event):
    global X, i
    #Transforming an event to time series (1,timesteps, columns)
    row = event.values.reshape(1,event.shape[0],event.shape[1])
    #Condition is needed to slice arrays correctly
    #Condition -> is timestep greater than the event's time series length? 
    if(timestep>=row.shape[1]):
        X[i:i+1,-row.shape[1]:,:] = row
    else:
        X[i:i+1,:,:] = row[:,-timestep:,:]
    #index to iterate over X array
    i = i + 1
    #dataframe remains intact, while X array has been filled.
    return event

df.groupby("event_id").apply(df_to_3darray)

#Dropping event_id to remove noise
X = X[:,:,1:]

#TODO: Padding with specific values column-wise instead of zeros.
#TODO: Separating time dependent and independent feature in 2 X arrays

print(X.shape, y.shape)
#computing scaled threshold 
th = np.array([threshold_for_classification]).reshape(-1,1)
th = y_scaler.transform(th)
threshold_scaled = th[0,0]




#Splitting arrays
y_boolean = (y > threshold_scaled).reshape(-1,1)
X_train, X_test, y_train_numeric, y_test_numeric = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    stratify=y_boolean, 
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    random_state=seed,
                                                    test_size = test_split
                                                  )

y_train_boolean = (y_train_numeric > threshold_scaled).reshape(-1,1)
X_train, X_val, y_train_numeric, y_val_numeric = train_test_split(X_train, y_train_numeric, 
                                                    stratify=y_train_boolean, 
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    random_state=seed,
                                                    test_size = val_split
                                                  )
#transforming it into a classification task -> y_train, y_test boolean
y_train = (y_train_numeric > threshold_scaled).reshape(-1,1)
y_val = (y_val_numeric > threshold_scaled).reshape(-1,1)
y_test = (y_test_numeric > threshold_scaled).reshape(-1,1)


X_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train,dtype=tf.int64)
X_test = tf.convert_to_tensor( X_test,dtype=tf.int64)
y_train_numeric = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train_numeric,dtype=tf.int64)    
y_test_numeric = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test_numeric,dtype=tf.int64) 
y_train_boolean = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train_boolean,dtype=tf.int64)
X_val = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_val,dtype=tf.int64)
y_val_numeric = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_val_numeric,dtype=tf.int64)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train,dtype=tf.int64)
y_val = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_val,dtype=tf.int64)
y_test = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test,dtype=tf.int64)
y_boolean = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_boolean,dtype=tf.int64)


#Percentage of high risks in train
print("TRAIN {:0.1f}, {:0.1f}, {:0.3f}".format(np.sum(y_train), y_train.shape[0], np.sum(y_train)/y_train.shape[0]))
#Percentage of high risks in val
print("VAL   {:0.1f}, {:0.1f}, {:0.3f}".format(np.sum(y_val), y_val.shape[0], np.sum(y_val)/y_val.shape[0]))
#Percentage of high risks in test
print("TEST  {:0.1f}, {:0.1f}, {:0.3f}".format(np.sum(y_test), y_test.shape[0], np.sum(y_test)/y_test.shape[0]))
# Model activation selu

input_tensor = Input(batch_shape=(batch, timestep, X_train.shape[2]))
rnn_1 = LSTM(32, stateful=False, dropout=0.15, recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=L1L2(l1=0.0, l2=0.01))(input_tensor)
batch_1 = BatchNormalization()(rnn_1)
rnn_2 = LSTM(16, stateful=False, dropout=0.15, recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=L1L2(l1=0.0, l2=0.01))(batch_1)
batch_2 = BatchNormalization()(rnn_2)
rnn_3 = LSTM(8, stateful=False, dropout=0.15, recurrent_dropout=0.3, return_sequences=False, kernel_regularizer=L1L2(l1=0.0, l2=0.01))(batch_2)
batch_3 = BatchNormalization()(rnn_3)
output_tensor = Dense(units = 1, activation='sigmoid')(batch_3)

model = Model(inputs=input_tensor,
              outputs= output_tensor)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model_history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                          epochs=epochs, 
                          batch_size=batch, 
                          #shuffle=True, #OJO
                          validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                          verbose=verbose,
                          class_weight=class_weight
                         ).history
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing this line

```py
input_tensor = Input(batch_shape=(batch, timestep, X_train.shape[2]))
```

to

```py
input_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(timestep, X_train.shape[2]))
```

and then defining your `batch_size` in `model.fit` and make sure `X_train` and `y_train` have the same number of samples.

Comment: Thank you. It works now by this change